# Ubuntu 22.04.2 bluetooth does not see wireless mouse

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, bluetooth, mouse

Ubuntu Bluetooth cannot find wireless mouse (Xiaomi Dual Mode Wireless Mouse Silent Edition).
Mouse works perfectly with MacOS and Windows. It also works with ubuntu via BT adaptor that comes with the mouse.

I tried a couple of things:

- Change BT mode in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. Setting ControllerMode = bredr or le
- Add `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

bluetoothctl scanning also does not see mouse...

Comment: This is one of the main features of Ubuntu, things don't work, and you don't have to worry about it any more.